# Why does a TextCtrl above a Bitmap only be visible after the mouseover?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have an TextCtrl on top of a Bitmap and when i access this panel, the TextCtrl is invisible and only be visible after the mouseover.

If I put the image in front of the TextCtrls, the fields appear but are inaccessible to the mouse, being only possible to manipulate them through the TAB.

I already tried to use the image as the background of the panel, but it did not work the way I would because it messed up the entire screen I had drawn.

My code:

```
def LoadBox(self):
    font = wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                   wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)

    font1 = wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                    wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
    font1.SetPixelSize(wx.Size(0, 20))

    font2 = wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                    wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)

    xPos1 = 131
    xPos2 = 392
    hFiel = 50
    wFiel = 80

    self.steV = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Text 1"),
                              pos=(255, 490), size=(200, hFiel))
    self.steV.SetFont(font)

    tctV1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos1, 316), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV1.SetFont(font2)

    tctV2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos2, 332), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV2.SetFont(font)

    tctV3 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos1, 362), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV3.SetFont(font2)

    tctV4 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos2, 378), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV4.SetFont(font)

    self.steV5 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("Text 2"), pos=(217, 410), 
                               style=TE_RIGHT)
    self.steV5.SetFont(font1)
    self.steV5.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(50,50,50))

    tctV5 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos1, 408), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV5.SetFont(font2)

    tctV6 = wx.TextCtrl(self, value='', pos=(xPos2, 424), size=(wFiel, -1))
    tctV6.SetFont(font)

    if self.osName == 'Windows':
        fontX = wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
                        wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
        fontX.SetPixelSize(wx.Size(0, 16))
        self.steV5.SetPosition((233, 410))
        self.steV5.SetSize(wx.Size((80, 20)))
        self.steV5.SetFont(fontX)
    else:
        self.steV5.SetSize(wx.Size((72, hFiel)))

    png = wx.Image('imgs/image.png',
                   wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, pos=(25, 245),
                                  size=(png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))
```

The problem only occurs in Windows, Linux is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text control to appear on top of the static bitmap then it needs to have the static bitmap as its parent, not whatever `self` is.

Comment: Just a note: this way only runs on Windows, on Linux there is a segmentation error.

Comment: RobinDunn just a question, after I put the fields as parent of the Bitmap, the TAB event no longer works. Would you perhaps know how to correct this? I searched for reference and the attempts I made failed all of them.